# Tax me more: Can I pay extra to the government so I don't have to deal with all this paperwork?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, electronic-filing

Is there a way to tell the US government: Just take all the money you like and save me the effort of the yearly filing of taxes?

Doing all this tax work is so annoying to me that I really would like to be able to say: "Government, you want 30% of my money? How about you keep 40%, 50% or 60%, and I don't have to deal with all this paperwork, calculations and record keeping?"

Is there a way to avoid the tax return filing requirement, perhaps by paying extra or forfeiting a refund?

Comment: If you have enough money, what you can do is pay someone (i.e., an accountant) to do all that tax work for you.

Comment: I hope someone can post the penalties/difficulties that occur when you don't file & don't owe anything since a quick search turned up nothing, only that it is "required".

Comment: If no record keeping was performed, how would you or the government know the dollar amount of that 40%, 50%, or 60%?

Comment: Are you asking about withholding taxes at source as is done in the (rest of?) civilized world?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a rant

Comment: It is not a rant @mhoran_psprep. I honestly want to know if an option exists where I pay more and get rid of all this drudgery

Comment: It would be simpler for the government and for tax payers if as an employee I could just file a "I don't care for a return" document and be done with this quickly @mhoran_psprep

Comment: I am actually surprised there isn't an option like that, it would mean more money for government, less hassle and stress for taxpayers and less bureaucratic work for everyone

Comment: Not sure @littleadv. What I would like is for my employer to pay the taxes before paying me... An that is it, if I don't want a return I have to do nothing (or just fill a really simple form saying: keep the money, let me be)

Comment: Perhaps what you are looking for is a less complex solution to the tax problem. The problem is that the tax code grows complex with the diverse rules, deductions, and exceptions added by our government, trying to nudge us to behave the way they want. The solution is at the ballot box, but realize that government has both greed and power as motivations to keep the existing system.

Comment: Part of the answer, if this question was to be taken seriously, is that the system isn't set up to handle this. It's not just the employer. When I sell stock at a gain, my broker would have to be sure to take the %XX cut you suggest. And when I have any taxable transaction, my freelance income, for instance. Those paying me would then take on this burden as well.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: Yes, in theory, the OP can ask the IRS to compute his tax for him. If this happens, the IRS will give itself the benefit of every doubt, and that will produce the result of: "Just take all the money you like and save me the effort of the yearly filing of taxes" I vote to reopen so I can post this answer.

Comment: You can minimize your paperwork burden by claiming the standard deduction and not bothering to look for/claim credits and whatnot. However you would also want to simplify your income - e.g. only get wages from a single source and avoid taxable investing. Once you do that, you'll still have to file taxes, but you can pay an accountant to do it for you. This would overall, probably cost you money, but still take effort - but the minimum effort you can legally get away with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a word, no. If your income is high enough to have to file a return, you have to file a return. My accountant has a nice mindset for making it more palatable. I'll paraphrase:

"Our tax system is ludicrously complicated. As a result, it is *your duty as an American to seek out and take advantage of every deduction and credit available to you*. If our politicians and leaders put it into the tax code, use it to your advantage."

A friend of mine got a [free golf cart](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/free-golf-cart-but-call-it-a-low-speed-neighborhood-vehicle/) that way. It was a crazy combination of credits and loopholes for electric vehicles. That loophole has been closed, and some would say it's a great example of him exercising his patriotic duty.

Comment: And in fact a random audit is as likely to turn up an opportunity you missed as an error in their favor, if you weren't actively trying to cheat.

Comment: "..., you have to file a return" Or else what?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, if you don't care about paying a bit more, either hire an accountant and dump the paper on them, or (may be cheaper but a bit more work) spring for tax software. Modern tax programs can often download most of your data directly. If you don't care about claiming deductions you can skip a lot of the rest.

I'm perfectly capable of doing my taxes on paper or in a spreadsheet... but I spring for tax software every year because I find it a **_LOT** more pleasant.

Remember that most of the complexity does come from policies intended to reduce your taxes. When you call for simplification, you may not like the result.

It's better than it was a decade or two ago. I used to joke that the battle cry of the next revolution would be "No Taxation Without Proper Instructions!"

Comment: +1 This. After years of doing my own, and then my partner's taxes by hand on paper, I finally bought software when I had to file my father's final taxes, which added a 2nd state to the mix. The returns aren't complicated enough to warrant a tax accountant.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the answer is no, you cannot get out of filing a tax return.  As noted in the comments, if you want to pay more to get out of the drudgery of working on your return, you can pay an accountant to do it for you.

You are not alone in thinking that the current income tax system in the U.S. is overly complicated.  What you are essentially describing is a [flat tax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_tax), a system where there would be a simple tax rate that is paid with no deductions, loopholes, etc., and minimal reporting requirements.

Besides flat tax proposals, others have proposed eliminating the income tax altogether and switching to a national sales tax, such as [the FairTax proposal](http://fairtax.org/).

Each of these proposals has pros and cons over the current system, and if you have questions about them, feel free to ask a new question.  But what they have in common is that they would drastically simplify the system of taxation in this country.  If that sounds good to you, you can learn more about these proposals and support organizations and candidates that advocate these reforms.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the real question you are asking is "*How can the tax code be fixed to make it simple for everyone (including me), and what would it take to effect those changes"?*

There are really two causes for the complexity of the tax code.

Many of those who enter Government hold a desire for power, and Government uses the tax code as one lever of power to distribute largess to their supporters, and to nudge everyone to behaviors which they favor. The current system enables incumbents to spend taxpayer money to reward those they favor, and thus they accumulate power and security.

Those who enter Government also love to spend money *(especially other people's money)*, and their rapacious behavior recognizes no boundaries. They will spend money without control until the taxpayers yank them to a brutal stop. They enact complex rules which are used to ease the (tax) burden for some, which buys their support (with taxpayer money), and they spend money to benefit those which they favor.

The system of lobbyists and contributors exists to entice Government to treat them and the causes they support favorably. This system enables incumbents to spend taxed money to reward those they favor, and to tax those they disfavor. Thus their greed is satisfied, and their power is increased.

The freedom you seek is not available, although you can minimize the effort required for compliance. You can take the standard deduction, and use nothing but the W-2 provided by your employer, and unless you are subject to the Alternative Minimum Tax, you will find that the tax software will do most of the work for you.

*Do you want to approach the Nirvana of minimal effort to appease your tax collectors? Avoid starting your own business, charitable donations, investment income, 1099 income, and you will need minimal paperwork. Avoid earning enough to risk the AMT (Alternative Minimum Tax). Refuse to take the mortgage interest deduction, tax credits for electric vehicles, tax credits for high-efficiency appliances and air conditioners, tax credits for residential solar panel installations. Do not own investments which pay interest, or own stocks where you need to track the "basis" (purchase price) of the stocks, nor buy and then sell valuable items that might gain value (where you would need to track the purchase price, the "basis"). Avoid owning and leasing a rental home for income, deducting businesses expenses and mileage for business purposes, contributions to a retirement plan (outside an employer plan) -- all complicate your tax filing.*

The solution you truly desire is either a "Flat Tax" or the "Fair Tax". These solutions would effect either a single tax rate *(with no deductions or adjustments to income, yeah right)*, or a national retail sales tax, which would tax the money spent in the economy regardless of the source of the money (legal, gifts, crime) and there would be no need to report income, or classify it. The largest objection to either is that the tax code might become less "progressive" (increasing tax rate with increasing income).

*Good Luck!*

Comment: What he wants works well in the rest of the world without any ridiculous "favor the rich" ideas. The fact that American tax system is utterly convoluted doesn't mean that tax system has to be utterly convoluted. In most of the world it is not. So instead of blaming some "government", blame "we the people" who has a constitution that gives power to the minority of voters which can be bought through money. When you switch to proportional representation (when everyone is represented, not only the 30% of those in your district that bothered to vote), you'll see things change.